# Front-Page.php and Index.php

Tags: template-hierarchy

So I have a front-page.php that is shown when a visitor visits my site.

I also want to create a blog page using my index.php file but I'm not sure what I need to do?

Do I just create a new page template for my blog page by copying and pasting my index.php code into my newly created page template file?

I haven't touched any of my reading setting either.

Does that make any sense?

Thanks

Comment: Index.php should be silenced unless you have good reason to use it. For your instance use a page template.

Comment: I think? What is your index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right way, but I used my front-page.php as my front page and then used my index.php as a page template when I created my blog page.

Comment: You set Front Page and Blog Page under `Settings -> Reading` which will take their respective templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a blog page from **index.php** If you have knowledge on WordPress Template hierarchy and WordPress coding standard you can easily manipulate blog page on your server.  Moreover **front-page.php** will be your home page.

Resources

[**Page Template Hierarchy**](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png)

[**Developer Resources:**](https://developer.wordpress.org/)